# How to locate static method in Kotlin in C++ JNI?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, java-native-interface

```
package com.example.flutter_app


class JNI {
    companion object {
        private fun loadWavAsset(assetMgr: AssetManager, assetName: String, index: String, pan: Float): Boolean {
    //...
    }
}
```

Then I'm caching the JNI like this: methodId: `loadWavAsset`, and signature `(Landroid/content/res/AssetManager;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;F)Z` and the class is `com/example/flutter_app/JNI`.

I believe this has something to do with static method on Kotlin. Are companion methods in Kotlin classes really static methods on JNI?

The other thing I suspect is `Float`. I'm not using `float` when I do `F` on the signature. Which should be the signature for `Float`?

Comment: Are you trying to locate kotlin method from native method?
To mark method as a static use `@JvmStatic` annotation: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#static-methods

Comment: @user882813 thanks, it worked by doing this and using `F` for `Float`